# How to do affine transformation for nifti image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, nifti

When i use `niftiinfo` for extracting the information of nifti image I got the following error.Is it possible to do affine transformation so that niftiinfo works properly

```
info = niftiinfo('Subject01.nii');
```

> Error using affine3d/set.T (line 340)
>       The final column of an affine transformation matrix must
>       consist of zeroes, except for a one in the last row.
>
> Error in affine3d (line 117)
>                       self.T = A;
>        Error in images.internal.nifti.niftiImage/getXForm (line 506)
>                       xform = affine3d([R zeros(3,1); T 1]');
>
> Error in images.internal.nifti.niftiImage/simplifyStruct (line 162)
>               [XformName, Xform] = self.getXForm();
>
> Error in niftiinfo (line 50)
>       simpleStruct = NV.simplifyStruct();

matlab 2018b yields

```
Filemoddate: '21-Jan-2015 13:44:48'
                 Filesize: 7256302
              Description: ''
                ImageSize: [39 305 305]
          PixelDimensions: [2 1.2500 1.2500]
                 Datatype: 'int16'
             BitsPerPixel: 16
               SpaceUnits: 'Unknown'
                TimeUnits: 'None'
           AdditiveOffset: 0
    MultiplicativeScaling: 0
               TimeOffset: 0
                SliceCode: 'Unknown'
       FrequencyDimension: 0
           PhaseDimension: 0
         SpatialDimension: 0
    DisplayIntensityRange: [0 0]
            TransformName: 'Qform'
                Transform: [1×1 affine3d]
                  Qfactor: 1
                      raw: [1×1 struct]
```

Comment: This smells like a bug, I would recommend creating a service request and if possible share this file or a similar file with data stripped which triggers this error. (https://www.mathworks.com/support/contact_us.html)

Answer (score 0):

Niftiinfo works fine for me on Matlab’s 2018a and 2018b, so I am willing to be that the issue is an incorrectly written nifti file, namely a problem with your srow_* and/or qform/sform codes. If you can post a header dump, I’m sure that would clearly illustrate a problem.

Comment: yes problem was with my qform/sform.can you explain it

Comment: I need to see the header or what the codes were, otherwise I don’t know what the problem is exactly.

Comment: updated headr from the information of matlab 2018b. first slice is 39 .i need to change it as 305 305 39

Comment: can you explain qform/sform

Comment: you can look at nibabel's documentation https://nipy.org/nibabel/nifti_images.html#the-sform-affine